# How to check that a particular class is assigned to a div and remove it using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Check if a particular class is assigned to a div and remove or replace it with another class using jQuery.

If there are two or more classes assigned to div, how to point out the exact class and remove it with the new one or just remove it from that element.

Is this can be used
`jquery addclass() or removeclass()` ?

or is there any other method ?

Comment: ``hasClass()`` to check and ``removeClass()`` to remove

Comment: @ehsan how should i referenced it in jquery because we need a selector to point out an element

Comment: you don't have any id or class on the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if an element has a class you can use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/).

But from what I understand from your question, you could just do:

`$('div.someClass').removeClass('someClass');`

This will select all `div`s that have `someClass` and remove it.

To replace the class you could do:

`$('div.someClass').toggleClass('someClass newClass');`

This will take all `div`s that have `someClass` and remove `someClass` and add `newClass`.

#### Update

If you want to remove/add a class on click you have two scenarios:

- you want to remove/add on the clicked element
- you want to remove/add on different element

For first scenario you can do like this:

```
$('div.someClass').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('someClass'); //your operation goes here. You can use $(this) to reference.
});
```

For the second you could do like this:

```
$('div.someClass').click(function(){
    $('div.someOtherDiv').removeClass('someOtherDiv'); //your operation goes here.
});
```

Comment: what if want to remove or add on click....basically what i am trying to achieve is same what is done in delicious.com, where u can select many divs and then process them together

Comment: Updated the answer. I don't know how delicious.com does it, but I assume they add a class to all selected `divs`s. If so, you use a selector like $('div.selectedDiv') to select them all.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('div').each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("className"))
  {
     $(this).removeClass("className");
  }
});
```

But if you just want to add class if not there and remove if there then you can use toggle function like below

```
$('div').each(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("className");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).hasClass( "nameclass" )
```

and

```
$( "mydiv" ).removeClass( "nameclass" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("div.classname").removeClass("classname");
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B7b5v/)**

**Note:** for a specific div do this:

```
$("#mySpecificDiv").toggleClass("classname");
```